# C++ Dll in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, pinvoke, dllimport

After looking for solutions already proposed to a similar question to mine, 
and since this is the first time I'm using a non-.NET DLL in a .NET application, 
I really need your help.

I have an WPF application, using MVVM Pattern, and in my `ViewModel` class I need to use a DLL done in C++ to recover a token. I have an example in C++ that uses this DLL, so I have the method's names, but I can't do the same in C#. I know that I must use `DllImport` to use this methods, but how implement it and use the pointer in C#??

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hinst = NULL;

    typedef bool ( *GetTokenProto )( char ** );
    typedef void ( *FreeTokenProto )( char * );

    GetTokenProto GetToken;
    FreeTokenProto FreeToken;

    std::string str = "DllName.dll";
    std::string token;

    if ( (hinst = LoadLibraryA(str.c_str()) ) )
    {
        GetToken = (GetTokenProto) GetProcAddress(hinst, "GetToken");
        FreeToken = (FreeTokenProto) GetProcAddress(hinst, "FreeToken");

        if (GetToken && FreeToken)
        {
            char *buf;
            if (GetToken(&buf))
            {
                token = buf;
                FreeToken(buf);

                std::cout << "Token:" << token << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "DLL loaded but no token" << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "DLL loaded but missing proc address(es)" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        FreeLibrary(hinst);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load DLL" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

```
[DllImport("DllName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetToken", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static extern bool get_token(ref string token); 

[DllImport("DllName.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeToken", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static extern void free_token(ref string token);

public static string a_token; 
public string get_token_method() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        string buffer = null; 
        if (get_token(ref buffer)) 
        { 
            a_token = buffer; 
            free_token(ref buffer); 
            Debug.WriteLine("token : " + a_refresh_token); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine("DLL Loaded but no token"); 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
       Debug.WriteLine("\n" + ex.Message); 
    } 
    return a_refresh_token; 
}
```

**The error**

> I have an Exception "System.DllNotFoundException" : Unable to load DLL
>   'DllName.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Dll file is in the same folder of the .exe (..\bin\Debug)

Comment: Is this a windows api call / DLL?

Comment: Yes, and used by another windows application but in c++ (like in the example), to recover a token (to be used after), and free this token

Comment: I mean, is this a Microsoft DLL? or just a custom DLL someone wrote, and is there any reason to load it explicitly?

Comment: Ah no, it's not a Microsoft dll, just a custom dll that i must use to recover this token (for authentication of my applcation). This an axample in C++ that use this dll (use "GetToken" and "FreeToken" methods)

Comment: Whats the header for GetToken function you want to use

Comment: All what i have, the .dll file that i put it in the same folder of my .exe application, and this C++ example that uses this dll

Comment: [DllImport("DllName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetToken", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool get_token(ref string token);
[DllImport("DllName.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeToken", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void free_token(ref string token);

Comment: public static string a_token;
public string get_token_method()
{
    try
    {
    string buffer = null;
        if (get_token(ref buffer))
        {
            a_token = buffer;
            free_token(ref buffer);
            Debug.WriteLine("token : " + a_refresh_token);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DLL Loaded but no token");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\n" + ex.Message);
    }
    return a_refresh_token;
}

Comment: I have an Exception "System.DllNotFoundException" : Unable to load DLL 'DllName.dll': The specified module could not be found. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). Dll file is in the same folder of the .exe (..\bin\Debug)

Comment: Sorry, that was meant be a comment, I'm not at my pc at the moment. I'll look into this a bit later

Comment: @Michael Randall, Ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DLL is in the same Directory, there are still a few things that might be the problem.

**Firstly**

The DLL may have dependencies

> The native DLL you use may have other dependencies which have to be
> installed ([try Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)). If the native DLL requires for
> example registry settings, config files etc. these should also be
> present. It should be distributed to user machines the same way you
> installed it on the dev machine.

Most likely you are missing the C++ redistributable package (which one I'm not sure) however Dependency Walker should tell you.

**Secondly**

It could be targeting a different bitness i.e x86 x64, so I'd try changing your project to see if that helps

> - Right click your project, and select properties.
> - In properties, select the build tab. Under platform target, select x86.
> - Hit Ctrl+Shift+S to save all files, right click the solution and select "Clean" to get rid of old binaries. Any builds after that
>   should be 32 bit

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I used the software and I found that the dll only depend on windows dll, so I deleted the dll from my directory and I added it a 2nd time, and there I had another exception BadImageFormatException, and what I did is that I recompiled my program (including the dll created in the same solution) by changing the target platform to x64 instead of Any CPU, because the dll is in x64 and here I can load the dll. thank you very much

Comment: There are some changes to make to my code, to do it like that of the c ++ that uses the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetDllDirectory method to set path of your dll before invoking your dll

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
```

Comment: Thanks, i explain what i did in the previous post

Comment: But the dll is in the same folder of my .exe, so i don't need to set her path, i can directly invoke it

Answer (score 0):

You should also use StringBuilder instead of string on c# side if you want to get string from c++.

Comment: I used it but that didn't work, so they gived me the dll code, so i modified it, and i created another function that return *char but without parameters, and to call this function i used a string like this: string token = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(get_token())  and that works perfectly. Thanks for the replay